# Microsoft Powerpivot button not working

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba, powerpivot

Hoping someone can assist me with this strange Powerpivot  issue; I have a single workbook which is not working with Powerpivot. It has a substantial amount of VBA code (much of which is related to securing the workbook) and clicking the Powerpivot button is having no effect.

When I open the workbook, the Powerpivot add in does not load (there is no Powerpivot tab available) and when I drag and drop the workbook into an instance of Excel opened independently (which already has the PP tab open), the Powerpivot button fails to open the window when it is clicked.

So far I have tried restarting and also disabling and re-enabling the Powerpivot addin.

My Powerpivot version is 10.50.4000.0 and I am on Excel 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this. While simply unlocking the worksheet and workbook did not work immediately, unlocking both, disabling the code that locked both at startup and then saving and re-opening did work.